# What is the meaning of "objective tendency"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

When I am reading [Philosophy and Simulation](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=TmbOBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false), I encountered the phrase:

> "objective tendency"

But I could not understand what the phrase means? Could you give me a synonym of this phrase?

> To understand how this works let's imagine two bodies of water at
>   different temperatures. The moment we place these bodies in contact
>   with each other energy will flow from the body with higher temperature to the one with lower temperature, the flow continuing until the temperature difference disappears. In other words, the difference in
>   temperature will display a tendency to average itself out . Thus, saying
>   that a body of water possess a certain temperature, and that possession of that property defines an enduring state, implies that departures from that state are constantly being counteracted by an objective
>   tendency.

Comment: Your writer seems to be the only person recorded by Google as having referred to, for example, [*objective possibility space*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22objective+possibility+space%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl), so I suggest either he particularly likes that word, or his English isn't good enough to come up with something more meaningful. Maybe ***inherent*** is more appropriate in the cited context, but perhaps "objective = **with an object** (aim) in mind = **purposeful**" (an "unusual" usage implying - the water "wants" to change its state).

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Manuel DeLanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_DeLanda)  is one of the most important philosophers on the earth but his english may be a little weak for writing a philosophy book in English.  _**inherent**_ seems better for this phrase.

Comment: This is one of the more understandable passages from the book but the meaning is still far from clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In philosophy, the adjective "[objective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objective)" means:

> existing outside of the mind : existing in the real world

I think the author wants to express that the counteraction is something that occurs in the real word. The tendency is objective (you can prove it), not subjective. A book of philosophy is not easy to understand

A term like "objective reality" is broadly used in philosophy which means "reality that exists in the real world".